# How to make a constructor return a subclassed object

Tags: design-patterns, oop, constructor, factory-pattern

I just read a book on object-oriented programming patterns.  It describes a Factory pattern by which you can make a call to a static factory method of an object and the object will return a new object of expected type, but it will be subclassed appropriately.

My question, can this functionality be provided by a constructor for the class?  If so how?  I f not why?  Imagine I have a class called VillagePerson, which has subclasses PoliceOfficer, NativeAmerican, Cowboy, Biker, ConstructionWorker, and Sailor.  The constructor takes a text string description of the person, parses it, and returns the specific type of person that I want.  Is this only possible with static factory methods?

Comment: The answer to this question is language specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This is a paraphrase of Steven Sudit's comment*

Create a [Proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern) class on top of the `VillagePerson`:

- The Proxy implements the same interface as `VillagePerson`, but does not inherit any implementation code from it.
- A Proxy contains a reference `_vpImpl` to a subclassed VillagePerson object.
- When a method is called on the Proxy, the Proxy simply passes the call to the `_vpImpl` object.

To construct a subclassed `VillagePerson`, the Proxy's constructor could call the specific constructor of the subclass and then store it in `_vpImpl`.

Comment: It is a paraphrase of Steven Sudit's comment.

Answer (score 3):

**No.** Usually, a constructor is a function that is called automatically by the language to *initialize* an object that is being created. This, in itself, means that the "call me to create an object" functionality of factories cannot be provided by a constructor.

Also, constructors are usually called from expressions like `new ClassName(args)` which are defined in most languages as creating an instance of `ClassName` and not of a class that inherits from `ClassName`. So, you can't use `new` or constructors to create instances of any type.

On the other hand, I did say "*in most languages*" : some, like JavaScript, let you return anything you want out of a constructor, and others, like Objective Caml, treat constructors as factory functions.

Comment: Your answer is correct, but there are ways to approximate dynamic typing even in statically-typed languages.  For example, the `VillagePerson` constructor can call a `VillagePersonImplFactory` static factory method to initialize its `_vpImpl` member.  Then, when its `Dance` method is called, it can chain the call to `_vpImpl`.  I'm sure the GoF design patterns book has some official label for this; I think something about templates.

Comment: @Steven Sudit: Yes. I do find using a factory method easier, though.